# How do I use XCTests to test for print statements?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, tdd, xctest

I am trying to test whether a function prints out something. How can I do this with XCTests? If this is possible, are there factual reasons to do it and not do it?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean printing to the console or the return result of a function?

Comment: @AlexBailey To the console!

Comment: Why would you want such a test? What purpose would the test serve? You have your reasons, I'm trying to learn the reasons behind the reasons.

Comment: @JonReid - I expect you probably found out the shell exists, and printing to stdout is it's gui. - That's one reason to test output.   To do so one creates a console print wrapper, to a protocol so you can mock it in tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know of a way to test a `print` statement, but I don't think it matters. The output of a `print` statement is irrelevant to what your app actually does. You should test what data your app changes, what it displays to the user, etc.

Comment: Hm, that's fair. I wanted to do it so that I could track when a function was triggered or did something. If I could test for a print statement, it would make it much easier. Do you know of a way to test if a function triggered with XCTests?

Comment: XCTest is similar to unit testing frameworks in other languages. Unit testing includes testing functions. You call your function and see whether it did what you expected. You may want to read up on how to write unit tests because it sounds like you may be unsure how to do this. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the advice @Mike Taverne! Will do!

Comment: This may be true(-ish) for a GUI application, but there are other kinds of programs. If the OP were writing a command line program, `print` might well be the way that everything is displayed to the user. Even a GUI app might have requirements to write certain data to standard out.

Comment: As @Caleb pointed out, there are good reasons why an app may be using the print function—such as CLI tools. So, the question remains: How to capture the output of print (and other output to stdout/stderr) using XCTest in Swift?

Answer (score 6):

@Mike Taverne is right.  For giggles if you did want to actually test against a print statement you could extend the print function like so:

```
var printWasWrittenTo: Bool = false

public func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    var output: String = items.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: separator)

    printWasWrittenTo = true //test against this variable being changed

    Swift.print(output, terminator: terminator)
}
```

Comment: I see. Alrighty then I won't use print statements to test! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a sideways view on this, if you have to check output, create a proxy that your app uses to control printing, conform it to a protocol and then mock it in tests.

For a simple example:

```swift
protocol POutput {
    func log(_ string: String)
}
```

with implementation:

```swift
public class Output: POutput {
    func log(_ string: String)
}
```

Use it by injecting it as a dependency for some function or object that needs to print, you'd inject an instance of `Output`, typed as `POutput` e.g.

```swift
func someCLIThing(out: POutput = Output()) { 
   out.log("print something")
}

// or

init(out: POutput = Output()) {
   self.out = out
}

func thatPrints() {
   out.log("print something")
}
```

To test you create a mock:

```swift
class MockOut: POutput {
    var logged = ""

    func log(_ string: String) {
        logged += string
    }
}
```

In your test, you can now check logged for the output vs expectation.

Now, as to why, or whether you should do this, it depends.

CLI apps will likely benefit from doing something like this, but if your `print` statements aren't crucial UI, then maybe not.

Headscratching comments on other answers, seem to imply a lot of folks think of `print` as something they only use for debugging (Much better to use breakpoints. You can log values, break conditionally, etc. etc. Bonus,  they don't end up in your commits, keeping your code tidy.)

Most CLI apps of any moderate size will pretty much require some way to test output, and it makes sense to use an injected dependency to take care of printing, so you can isolate it and mock it.

Plus you then get to augment it with ANSI color and other output features.

**Note**: The `log` function is purely an example, if you want to duplicate the functionality of `Swift.print` the full signature is

```
func print(
    _ items: Any...,
    separator: String = " ",
    terminator: String = "\n"
)
```

I'd recommend that you don't name it `print` so that it's clearly identifiable.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/print(_:separator:terminator:)